# How to prevent scaling of background image using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, web-frontend

I have a high-resolution image that is the **background** image of a div. The div keeps rendering it at a smaller size but I would like to leave it unscaled. I don't mind that the background image is cropped to show only a portion of the image as long as that portion has the original size.

Javascript:

```
console.log(img.width) // this comes out 3840px
resultDiv.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')"; 
resultDiv.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
```

CSS:

```
.img-full {//this is the class of the img

    max-width: none;
    max-height: none;
}

#bottomPanel {//this is the resultDiv that is scaling the background image

    height: 30vh;
    background: black;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: here is the good example have a look => https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/10/object-fit-background-size-css/

Comment: @Ouroborus added it

Comment: What do you mean by "scaling to a lower resolution"? That's not what browsers do. Scaling an image does not alter its resolution. Please use more accurate terminology.

Comment: **Please post your HTML**. It sounds like you're abusing an `<img class="img-full" />` element to specify a background image - so why do you have that when `div#resultPanel` is **not** an `img`? Also, `max-width` specifies CSS box-size, and has nothing to do with `background-image`.

Comment: @Dai I have img-full to keep the image at 3840px. Otherwise, it gets rendered smaller. I do use it in other places, hence the need for max-width.

Comment: @moii789 You don't need to use `<img />` in order to do that. You can use pure CSS.

Comment: You should post your HTML, the guesswork here makes it very hard to help.

Comment: @ Dai How do I prevent the div from rendering it at a smaller size though?

Comment: @moii789 Again, we cannot help you _until and unless_ you post your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the following CSS Property

```
background-size: cover;
```

this will make sure the background covers the whole element regardless if it was cropped or not, different that

```
background-size: contain;
```

that will scale the image to be fit within the element and to be fully visible

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I am trying to prevent scaling.

Comment: @moii789 you can also explicitly specify the width (and/or height) in pixels ...

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to prevent scaling by using `background-size: cover`.
This crops the background, and it never stretches for me.

More info about `background-size`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size